# Oracle/SQL: Regexp Similar to LIKE-% but wildcard mandatory (not optional)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm in Oracle 10, and need an equivalent of

`where col like 'str%'`

but where the %-part is not optional. The result of `str` is not allowed.

Is the following correct?

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col, '^str(*)+');
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php

Reason:
1) Match any character, `(*)`
2) Occurrence must be at least 1, `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_`:

```
where col like 'str_%'
```

This requires at least one character after the `'str'`.

If you want regular expressions, the simplest is probably:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col, '^str.');
```